# When exactly will the result of a SQL join collapse two columns into one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I use PostgreSQL quite frequently, and I've observed that some equality joins merge the two columns involved in the equality comparison into a single column in the result set, and some don't. It seems to be related to whether or not the join is INNER or OUTER, and also whether or not the join condition is expressing with the USING syntax or ON syntax. I'd like to know when exactly the two columns are collapsed/merged into one, or even better: I'd like to know where this behavior is specified.

Comment: Please can you provide the SQL statements ?

Comment: The question is good, but it *needs* a code example. Please update.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, not adding code examples for two reasons: 1) It was readily understandable, as evidenced by answer(s) below, and 2) A good example is provided below. I still really would like to know where, if anywhere other than the postgresql documentation, it is specified that the USING clause has this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be collapsed when `using` is used

```
create table a (id int);
create table b (id int);

select *
from
    a
    inner join
    b using (id);
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

If `on` is used it will return two columns:

```
select *
from
    a
    inner join
    b on a.id = b.id;
 id | id 
----+----
(0 rows)
```

And the column without a table name qualification is ambiguous

```
select id
from
    a
    inner join
    b on a.id = b.id;
ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: select id from a inner join b on a.id = b.id;
```

The same for `outer join`

```
select *
from
    a
    full outer join
    b on a.id = b.id;
 id | id 
----+----
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that a table-qualified reference is *always* valid even when joining with the `USING` clause which by default outputs a single instance of the merged column.

Comment: @Erwin Good, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Is this specified somewhere in the SQL standard?